# how to select a div when a radio button is checked

Tags: html, css

I have divs with the class (both), I want to select and apply styles to them when radio button with the ID (free) is checked. How would the CSS selector look like?

Comment: On SO, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use jQuery to achieve this:

```
$('#free').change(function() {
    //if checkbox checked
    if(this.checked){
        $('.both').addClass('newstyle');
    }
    //if the checkbox is not checked or unchecked
    if(!this.checked){
        $('.both').removeClass('newstyle');
    }
});
```

Here is a simple fiddle to demonstrate: https://jsfiddle.net/p3wc4ex6/1/

If you're looking for pure CSS [G-Cyr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46626206/how-to-select-a-div-when-a-radio-button-is-checked/46626603#46626603) is awesome

Answer (score -1):

CSS selector would either look like:

- `#free:checked ~ .both`
- `#free:checked ~  .parent_of_both .both`

Which means that `#free` must be ahead in the flow and `.both` a sibbling or inside a sibbling of `#free`.

*an example with label and css hidden radio inputs https://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/JFdEk .*

If HTML does not match the CSS selector requirements, then javaScript is required.